# how to render twig template and return function zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, twig, render, viewmodel

I'm migrating from zend framework 1 to 3 , and I have a function that returns twig template but I don't know what should I use to render view twig template on zf3

How to:

- use class of viewer
- set my template path
- set array to render it in template
- return template

code:

```
protected function convertItemList($aItemList)
{
    $aSet = [];
    //$config['template_paths'] = [APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Core/Backend/SRO/Views/'];
    //$oView = new Core_Twig_View($config);
    if (!$aItemList) {
        return [];
    }
    foreach ($aItemList as $iKey => $aCurItem) {
        $aSpecialInfo = [];
        $aInfo = $aCurItem;
        $aInfo['info'] = $this->getItemInfo($aCurItem);
        $aInfo['blues'] = $this->getBluesStats($aCurItem, $aSpecialInfo);
        $aInfo['whitestats'] = $this->getWhiteStats($aCurItem, $aSpecialInfo);
        //$oView->assign('aItem', $aInfo);
        $i = isset($aCurItem['Slot']) ? $aCurItem['Slot'] : $aCurItem['ID64'];
        if ($aCurItem['MaxStack'] > 1) {
            $aSet[$i]['amount'] = $aCurItem['Data'];
        }
        $aSet[$i]['TypeID2'] = $aInfo['TypeID2'];
        $aSet[$i]['OptLevel'] = $aInfo['OptLevel'];
        $aSet[$i]['RefItemID'] = !isset($aCurItem['RefItemID']) ? 0 : $aCurItem['RefItemID'];
        $aSet[$i]['special'] = isset($aInfo['info']['sox']) && $aInfo['info']['sox'] ? true : false;
        $aSet[$i]['ItemID'] = $aCurItem['ID64'];
        $aSet[$i]['ItemName'] = $aInfo['info']['WebName'];
        $aSet[$i]['imgpath'] = $this->getItemIcon($aCurItem['AssocFileIcon128']);
        //$aSet[$i]['data'] = $oView->render('itemData.twig');
    }
    return $aSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this module https://github.com/OxCom/zf3-twig. 
You can install it by github instructions and add this parameter to zf3 configuration array:

```
   'service_manager' => array(
      'factories' => array(
         ...
         'TwigStrategy' => \ZendTwig\Service\TwigStrategyFactory::class,
         ...
       ),
    )
```

1) After this you can use Twig in some action of some controller by this code:

```
   function someAction(){
      ...

      $viewModel = new ZendTwig\View\TwigModel(['foo'=>'bar']);
      return $viewModel;
   }
```

2) To set other template:

```
   function someAction(){
      $viewModel = new ZendTwig\View\TwigModel(['foo'=>'bar']);
      $viewModel->setTemplate('application/controller/name'); //set path here
      return $viewModel;
   }
```

3) You can to set array variables by TwigModel "__construct" parameter:

```
   function someAction(){
      $viewModel = new ZendTwig\View\TwigModel($someVariablesArray);
      $viewModel->setTemplate('application/controller/name'); //set path here
      return $viewModel;
   }
```

4) If you need to return html code, you need to do something:

- Add in services config one more param:

```
   'service_manager' => array(
      'factories' => array(
         ...
         'TwigStrategy' => \ZendTwig\Service\TwigStrategyFactory::class,
         'TwigRenderer'  => \ZendTwig\Service\TwigRendererFactory::class,
         ...
       ),
    )
```

- Add TwigRenderer service in your controller factory:

```
class YourControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
   public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
   {
      return new YourController($twigRenderer);
   } 
}
```

and get twigRenderer in your Controller:

```
   private $twigRenderer;

   public function __construct($twigRenderer)
   {
      $this->twigRenderer = $twigRenderer;
   }
```

- After this get html:

```
   function someAction(){

      $viewModel = new ZendTwig\View\TwigModel(['foo'=>'bar']);
      $viewModel->setTemplate('mails/order/order_in_process');
      $html = $this->twigRenderer->render($viewModel);
      return $html;
   }
```

Sorry for my english!